# How to delete broken references from mongodb array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bluebird

I had an error in my software leading to broken references in my mongodb.
An example website document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58d55766f12ba71c4131468a"),
"name" : "abc",
"annotations" : [ 
  ObjectId("58d5580b507af01cc77c5155"), 
  ObjectId("58d55888b83e461d768fc0eb"), 
  ObjectId("58d8d0b434f0b621272869be"), 
  ObjectId("58d8d0f034f0b621272869bf")
]
```

Where some of the ObjectIds in the array don't exist any more.
I'm trying to find a way to delete the broken references to the annotation object.
This is what I'm trying to do:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

mongoose.connect(config.get("DBUrl"), {useMongoClient: true});

require('./model/Website');
require('./model/Annotation');

const Website = mongoose.model('Website');
const Annotation = mongoose.model('Annotation');


Website.find({})
    .then(function (websites) {

        for (let website of websites) {

            let queue = [];

            for (let annotationId of website.annotations) {

                queue.push(Annotation.find({_id: annotationId}, {_id: 1})
                    .then(function (ann) {
                        if (!ann) {
                            website.pull(annotationId);
                        }
                        return Promise.resolve(website);
                    })
                );
            }

            Promise.all(queue)
                .then(function (ws) {
                    console.log('updated website ' + website.name)
                    return website.save();
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    throw new Error(err);
                });
        }
    });
```

I can't get the Promise.all working. It's executed before the .then of the find functions.
Please help me to find the error.

Is there maybe a more elegant way to do this using plain mongodb?

Thank You

Comment: I would skip that second for loop (annotationId of website.annotations) and instead make a query such as `Annotation.find({_id: {$in: website.annotations}})` then compare the result of the query to the original list. you could just set website.annotations to the resulting array if you're not worried about race conditions.
maybe look at lodash to easily find the difference between two arrays if you need that (make sure to .toString() objectIds before comparing them)
I would also consider using async or streams here instead of promise.all (especially when number of websites can be large)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the example in the question doesn't work. But: 
Here is what worked in the end:

```
Website.find({})
    .then(function (websites) {

        for (let website of websites) {

            let queue = [];

            for (let annotationId of website.annotations) {

                queue.push(Annotation.find({_id: annotationId}, {_id: 1})
                    .then(function (ann) {
                        if (!ann) {
                            website.pull(annotationId);
                        }
                        return Promise.resolve(website);
                    })
                );
            }

            Promise.all(queue)
                .then(function (ws) {
                    console.log('updated website ' + website.name)
                    return website.save();
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    throw new Error(err);
                });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but a general idea of how I would do it using Async.js and Lodash.

I don't really use Bluebird (and by the looks of their documentation, I doubt I ever will).

```
async.series([
    // get all annotation IDs
    done => Annotation.distinct('_id').exec(done),
    // get all websites
    done => Website.find({}).exec(done)
], function (err, results) {
    let annotationIDs = results[0].map(String), 
        websites = results[1];
    // loop through each website
    async.eachSeries(websites, function (website, done) {
        // reset the annotations with only ones that exist
        website.annotations = _.intersection(website.annotations.map(String), annotationIDs)
        website.save(done);
    }, function (err) => {
        // all done
    });
});
```

I've had issues comparing two arrays of ObjectIDs, so I cast them to Strings just in case.